# Match TextBox(es) with Labels

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, label

At runtime, I am querying an access table and storing the results in an array.  So for example, the data structure of that access table is

```
SalespersonName ------ Item1Sold ----- Item2Sold ---------- Item3Sold
Mitch                  Boat            Camera
Jason                  Car             Shells
Mitch                  Eggs
Richard                Coffee          Bacon                 Beans
```

I am wanting to create a label that holds SalespersonName & create a textbox beside the SalesPerson name that would display all non blank itemsold fields.  So my desired output would be

```
(label) Mitch (textbox) Boat (textbox) Camera
(label) Jason (textbox) car (textbox) shells
(label) Mitch (textbox) Eggs
(label) Richard (textbox) Coffee (textbox) bacon (tetbox) beans
```

I can't figure out how to only produce the textbox if the value is not null.  I am only able to do such for all or nothing which is not what I am after.

Code to add everything below

```
string path = "A:\\Database1.mdb";
object oName = path;
System.Collections.Hashtable lookup = new System.Collections.Hashtable();
OleDbConnection olecon = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" +  oName);
olecon.Open();
OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM info", olecon);
dr = command.ExecuteReader();
while (dr.Read())
{
   fields.Add(dr[0].ToString());
}
dr.Close();
foreach (string field in fields)
{
   Label labelz = new Label();
   labelz.Name = "labelz_" + index;
   labelz.Text = label;
   labelz.AutoSize = true;
   labelz.Location = new Point(10, 30);
   panel1.Controls.Add(labelz);

   TextBox textboxes = new TextBox();
   textboxes.Name = "txt_" + index;
   textboxes.Location = new Point(10, 80);
   textboxes.AutoSize = true;
   panel1.Controls.Add(textboxes);
   if (field != "")
   {
     panel1.SetFlowBreak(textboxes, true);
   }

   index++;
}
```

Comment: Please show your code how you do for all? It would be easier to point you where you could make fixes.

Comment: @Reniuz code to add all added.

Comment: use `DataGridView` for this purpose!

Comment: @HamidP I can see how using a DataGridView would make the returning data cleaner, but still back to my original ? how would that make the textbox association work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well your code not adding all components. It adds label with text in label variable and text box. I suggest you to split logic in two parts:

- Retrieve data and hold it in more comfortable to manipulate structure - create a class that holds required data from database.
- Use data to create components in required layout.

How it could be done(not tested pseudo code):

---

First part:

```
//data class
class Person
{
  public string Name {get;set;}
  public List<string> SoldItems {get;set;}
}

//fill data
List<Person> Persons = new List<Person>();
int itemColumnCount = 3;
while (dr.Read())
{
  Person person = new Person();
  person.SoldItems = new List<string>();
  //Get person name
  person.Name = dr.GetString(dr.GetOrdinal("personNameColumn"));
  //Get sold items
  for(int i = 1; i <= itemColumnCount; i++)
  {
    //lets say you have columns: ItemSoldColumn1, ItemSoldColumn2, ItemSoldColumn3 for example
    string columnName = "ItemSoldColumn" + i;
    //check if column value is not null
    if(!dr.IsDBNull(dr.GetOrdinal(columnName)))
    {
      string soldItem = dr.GetString(dr.GetOrdinal(columnName));
      //add to persons sold items list
      person.SoldItems.Add(soldItem);
    }
  }
}
```

---

Part two:

```
foreach(var person in Persons)
{
   //create label and set text to persons name
   //...
   newLabel.Text = person.Name;
   //add to panel or some kind of layout control

   //here you will have only sold items which is not null in database
   //so just loop through sold items list and create texboxes   
   foreach(var item in person.SoldItems)
   {
     //create textbox
     newTextBox.Text = item;
     //add to panel or some kind of layout control
   }
}
```

P.s. think about changing database structure into Persons --< SoldItems relation.

Comment: Would I 1st have to query to get the item column count since this would be unknown initially?

Comment: Yes. But to be more elegant(adding repeated columns is not good design) create two tables one to store persons and other to store sold items.

Comment: I was just wondering how to get the count for itemColumnCount.  How would I have that info w/o 1st querying the database?

Comment: There is [FieldCount](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbdatareader.fieldcount(v=vs.110).aspx) property in datareader which returns all column count. Then you can substract amount of columns which will be known initially or  you may loop through all column names and take only those which name starts for example "ItemSold".